# Can you actually hatch a Pichu with the Ash hat?

Tags: pokemon-go

I saw on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6lps8x/psa_pichu_can_hatch_with_ashs_hat/) that someone hatched a Pichu with an Ash hat during the one year anniversary event.  In previous hat events, [Pichu couldn't hatch with a hat](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294410/can-a-pichu-wearing-a-santa-hat-hatch-from-an-egg).

Someone in the Reddit claimed they hatched an egg they received during the event and didn't get a Pichu with a hat:

> Got an egg during the event and hatched it last night for a Pichu without a hat.

Is it possible to hatch one with a hat and if so, is it guaranteed to have a hat during the event or random?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### YES, you can.

I hatched one this morning from a 2k egg, which I believe I got yesterday (i.e. after the "event" began). I've taken a screenshot, with the pichu at an angle for authenticity. ;)

[image]

I didn't realize it was possible, as the previous two hatted pikachus came before the baby pokemon were added.

Not sure if you have a definite chance of getting one with a hat or not, unfortunately.

Comment: For better authenticity, you can name your Pichu as your Arqade profile name ;)

Comment: What, you don't trust me? ;) That's not a bad idea.

Comment: It's not that I don't trust your answer, but seeing how it conflicted with the other answer, the more validity the better :)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it's guaranteed, but the first two 2km eggs I've hatched since the event started (and picked up since then too) were Ash Hat Pichu's.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I hatched it from a 2km egg without any tricks. Didn't even know it was possible.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I just hatched a Pichu with Ash's hat.  I had no idea that was even possible, but it happened.  It wasn't even from a 10k egg.  I only had 2k and 5k eggs in my bag.  However, I believe I got the egg from the pokestop where I caught my Pikachu with Ash's hat.  Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: Such a claim would need photo evidence with your username as its name for the validity that the Pokemon is one, real, and two, yours and not someone's Pokemon. This has been discussed in the comments under the top answer