# Does the Pikachu event hat have any effect?

Tags: pokemon-go

Niantic celebrates 1 Year of Pokémon Go with another special Pikachu.
It will most likely be limited like the [Christmas Pikachu](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294383/why-is-pikachu-wearing-a-santa-hat-and-what-does-it-mean), but with a new hat.

[image: pika chuuuu]

The linked question has no information about the actual effect the hat has on Pikachu and Niantic doesn't tell us either. Does it even have one or is it purely cosmetic?

Comment: In case it is the same as with the Christmas Event (which I assume), no: it is purely cosmetic.

Comment: @CrowleyAstray Why don't you make that into an answer?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer because I had no concrete evidence nor source. I didn't want to risk answering just so it turns out they did it different this time around.

Comment: @CrowleyAstray Then why offer information you're not certain about? What if you're wrong? We can't downvote comments.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I would have deleted it, obviously. I for my part prefer to have my question answered in comments even if it's not certain over not getting an answer at all.

Comment: @CrowleyAstray And what if you were correct, and the asker wasn't able to show that by accepting your answer? What is the benefit of answering in a comment over an answer, even if you're not 100% sure of what you're saying? If you could only post answers you were sure of, we wouldn't need to vote them. Please use answers if you're going to attempt to solve the asker's problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[One article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/erikkain/2017/07/06/heres-everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-pokemon-go-anniversary-event/#22014e0c538c) claims that the hat is cosmetic only:

> The hat is only a cosmetic. Ash Hat Pikachu will have the same stats as regular Pikachu, just with an adorable hat.

Historically, the last two times Pikachu had a hat, it was cosmetic as well.  Niantic hasn't officially stated if this is true or not.  A few other sites, such as [this one](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-07-06-pokemon-go-ash-hat-pikachu-anniversary-event-anniversary-box-4819) are also claiming that the hat is cosmetic only and make comparisons to the previous hats Pikachu has worn before.